# Openshift Admin Token

Tags: kubernetes, openshift, openshift-enterprise

I am trying to create a script that records project resources every 15 minutes. How do I authenticate with Openshift API? Is there a token I can use that has read access on all namespaces? How do I create a service account that has access over all namespaces?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to create a ClusterRole that has read access to the resources and use  ClusterRoleBinding to associate the ServiceAccount to that ClusterRole. Rough example, not tested but it should work:

```
# creates the service account "ns-reader"
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: ns-reader
  namespace: default

---
kind: ClusterRole
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  # "namespace" omitted since ClusterRoles are not namespaced
  name: global-reader
rules:
- apiGroups: [""]
  # add other rescources you wish to read
  resources: ["pods", "secrets"] 
  verbs: ["get", "watch", "list"]

---
# This cluster role binding allows service account "ns-reader" to read pods in all available namespace
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: read-ns
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: ns-reader
  namespace: default
roleRef:
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: global-reader
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
```

When the ServiceAccount is setup, a number of secrets are created automatically associated with it. A couple of these secrets hold a token which can then be used when using the REST API directly or using `oc`. Use `oc describe` on the ServiceAccount to see the names of the Secret for the tokens. Then use `oc describe` on one of the Secrets to see the token.