# Service account role bindings not working for API access

Tags: kubernetes, openshift

I am working on developing tools to interact with Kubernetes. I have OpenShift setup with the allow all authentication provider. I can log into the web console as I would expect.

I have also been able to setup a service account and assign a cluster role binding to the service account user. Despite this, when I access the REST API using a token of that service account, I get forbidden.

Here is what happens when I try to setup role bindings via OpenShift commands:

```
[root@host1 ~]# oadm policy add-cluster-role-to-user view em7 --namespace=default
[root@host1 ~]# oadm policy add-cluster-role-to-user cluster-admin em7 --namespace=default
[root@host1 ~]# oadm policy add-cluster-role-to-user cluster-reader em7 --namespace=default


[root@host1 ~]# oc get secrets | grep em7
em7-dockercfg-hnl6m         kubernetes.io/dockercfg               1         18h
em7-token-g9ujh             kubernetes.io/service-account-token   4         18h
em7-token-rgsbz             kubernetes.io/service-account-token   4         18h


TOKEN=`oc describe secret em7-token-g9ujh | grep token: | awk '{ print $2 }'`


[root@host1 ~]# curl -kD - -H "Authorization: Bearer $TOKEN" https://localhost:8443/api/v1/pods
HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
Cache-Control: no-store
Content-Type: application/json
Date: Tue, 19 Jun 2018 15:36:40 GMT
Content-Length: 260

{
  "kind": "Status",
  "apiVersion": "v1",
  "metadata": {},
  "status": "Failure",
  "message": "User \"system:serviceaccount:default:em7\" cannot list all pods in the cluster",
  "reason": "Forbidden",
  "details": {
    "kind": "pods"
  },
  "code": 403
}
```

I can also try using the yaml file from ([Openshift Admin Token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49667239/openshift-admin-token)):
    # creates the service account "ns-reader"
    apiVersion: v1
    kind: ServiceAccount
    metadata:
      name: ns-reader
      namespace: default

```
---
kind: ClusterRole
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  # "namespace" omitted since ClusterRoles are not namespaced
  name: global-reader
rules:
- apiGroups: [""]
  # add other rescources you wish to read
  resources: ["pods", "secrets"]
  verbs: ["get", "watch", "list"]

---
# This cluster role binding allows service account "ns-reader" to read pods in all available namespace
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: read-ns
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: ns-reader
  namespace: default
roleRef:
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: global-reader
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
```

When I run this, I get the following error:

```
[root@host1 ~]# kubectl create -f stack_overflow_49667238.yaml
error validating "stack_overflow_49667238.yaml": error validating data: API version "rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1" isn't supported, only supports API versions ["federation/v1beta1" "v1" "authentication.k8s.io/v1beta1" "componentconfig/v1alpha1" "policy/v1alpha1" "rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1alpha1" "apps/v1alpha1" "authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1" "autoscaling/v1" "extensions/v1beta1" "batch/v1" "batch/v2alpha1"]; if you choose to ignore these errors, turn validation off with --validate=false
```

I have tried several different API versions from the list but they all failed in a similar way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`oadm policy add-cluster-role-to-user view em7` grants to the user named `em7`

you need to grant permissions to the service account, e.g. `oadm policy add-cluster-role-to-user view system:serviceaccount:default:em7`

Comment: Also read http://cookbook.openshift.org/users-and-role-based-access-control/how-do-i-enable-rest-api-access-for-an-application.html for details of enabling REST API access for an application.